# Plugin Flutter not working, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Flutter is not running on my Android Studio correct, the emulator does not open the Standart beginning App. I believe it is because of some internal mixed up. I reinstalled everything without success. Right now when I run flutter doctor this is shown:
[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5zHI.png)

Can I put the plugins manually in some Folder? Because opening Android Studio and just downloading the plugin does not change anything. Although I can now create flutter Projects and come as far as writing the code but not seeing the app.
Any Response is helpfull!

Comment: I hope you mean /android-studio/plugins because that is all i could find. There was no sign of anything regarding flutter nor Dart. Do you want me to list the rest?

Comment: no, i meant your home folder, something starting with `/home/pilki/.AndroidStudio`, execute for example the command: `ls -ld /home/pilki/.AndroidStudio*`

Comment: I have no Folder which is called AndroidStudio. I only have AndridStudioProjects

Comment: ls: cannot access '/home/pilki/.AndroidStudio*': No such file or directory

Comment: did you try to run a app with android studio,this usually shows after 4.1 update,i don't think there won't problem with run app and debug,i have same but i can develop and deploy app without any problem,try to run a sample app@Pilki

Comment: @Assassin Well, the emulator does run but without the flutter app

Comment: Where can I see it?

Comment: You were right. I can ran an app but only over the terminal.. The flutter App does not work when opened inside android studio

Answer (score 1):

Your flutter doctor clearly shows that the correct plugins(Dart and Flutter) are not installed. To install the plugins just follow the steps:

- File->Settings->Plugins-> Type/ To see options. Here search for flutter.
- Install the plugin and restart the Android Studio.
- If you face any kind of problem after restarting try doing the following:
  File-> Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Flutter doctor output, your android studio is missing Flutter and Dart Plugins. to install them,

Open Android Studio and open settings and go to plugins and search for Flutter. install it and the Dart plugin. then restart the android studio

Comment: I already tried that. In my android studio I even see the create new flutter project Button. But flutter doctor does not change and the emulator does not show the project too

Comment: can you try running the flutter doctor as root if possible?

Comment: I did it just now and it downloaded a lot but it did't change the outcome